# CSS, UL/OL: Incorrect indent with custom counter

Tags: css, html-lists, counter, before-filter

Update: *this* problem has found a very satisfactory solution, but in production side effects popped up which I describe in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896003/again-css-ul-ol-incorrect-indent-with-custom-counter).

---

So, I'm using a custom counter in my OLs to get numbering like "1 - 1.1 - 1.1.1"
Works fine.

<del>But when I do this, the indentation of the LI is wrong. The text aligns with the left edge of the number, not with the right edge (like standard OLs do).</del>
Edit: To get the numbers layouted the way I want, I had to mess with the standard paddings/margins of the OL.
Now the text aligns with the left edge of the number, not with the right edge (like standard OLs do).

I've tried numerous things, but somehow I can't seem to control the left edge of the LI content.
Also, this feature apparently isn't used terribly often, so web searches didn't yield any hints :-(

Does anybody have an idea what I've been missing?

Below, you find both the CSS and the HTML, and I have put a test case into this cssdesk: http://cssdesk.com/EzPBG

---

CSS:

```
ol.wrong {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  counter-reset: counter_level1;
  list-style: none outside none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  width: 500px;
}
ol.wrong li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right:20px;
}
ol.wrong li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  content: counter(counter_level1) ". ";
  counter-increment: counter_level1;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20px;
}

ol.wrong ol {
  counter-reset: counter_level2;
}  
ol.wrong ol li {
  margin-right:0px;
}
ol.wrong ol li:before {
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  content: counter(counter_level1, decimal) "." counter(counter_level2, decimal) ". ";
  counter-increment: counter_level2;
}
```

HTML

```
  <ol class="wrong">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <ol>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <ol>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: You have a nice problem here but your question statement could be made clearer.  The layout problem has to do with styling the pseudo-elements that you are using to display your counter values.  Since you have turned off the default list style in your lists, the indentation in now entirely up to you.  This is the issue that you really need help with.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'll add that to my text.

Comment: Where are the floated images? and why did you unaccept my original answer? you are now proposing a different problem so it would be acceptable to pose a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I handled this the wrong way. I'll re-accept your answer and post the updated problem in a new question.

Comment: I appreciate that.  The advantage of posting a new question is that it will get proper attention, whereas an updated but older question will not be seen.  Just remember, this is a volunteer community and points are the only thanks participants get for helping each other out.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
ol.wrong {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  counter-reset: counter_level1;
  list-style: none outside none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  width: 500px;
}
ol.wrong li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right:20px;
  padding-left: 20px; /* create some space for the counter label */
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
ol.wrong li:before {
  display: inline-block; /* block would also work */
  position: absolute; /* move this out of the way of the text*/
  left: 0; /* move the counter labe into the space from the padding */
  content: counter(counter_level1) ". ";
  counter-increment: counter_level1;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20px;
}
```

and you can check the code at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/wsmnJ/

The pseudo-element trick is quite useful, and a good choice in this application.

Start by adding some padding to the left for `ol.wrong li`, this will create some white space for placing your label.

In your pseudo-element styling, `ol.wrong li:before`, use `position: absolute` to remove the label out of the way of the text and position it `left: 0`.  The display type can be either `block` or `inline-block`.

You then follow suit for the inner, nested `ol`.

Just created padding to the left equal in width to the width that you need for your counter/label element.

Comment: That ... is full of stars. It works in my test case, I'll check whether it works in the project code.

Comment: "That... is full of stars." ... that is a new expression! :)

Comment: It works in the production environment. Thank you so much \o/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marc Audet, interesting CSS, however by dispensing with HTML's natural way to deal with nested lists you've created your own little world to contend with. As far as I understand it there are three possible ways to deal with this:

Firstly, go back to the standard native way to deal with nested lists as you have with your "standard indentation" list.

Secondly, add something like this to the pseudo-element...

```
ol.wrong li:before {
  float:left;
  height:80px;
}
```

...The floating of the pseudo-element kicks the rest of the LI to the right, however setting the height to a fixed value isn't very flexible unless you can guarantee that all LIs will be the same height (alternatively you can set several heights and choose whichever suits each particular LI... again, though, rather clunky).

Finally, taking the above idea and adding some javascript to deal with changing the height of the pseudo-element on the fly... if this is even possible.

Comment: This approach has merits and the height issue can be easily fixed.  Why don't you set up a fiddle?

Comment: Interesting solution, but unfortunately the height needs to be flexible. Thank you very much for spending time on this though :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, @Marc Audet, my jQuery skills are adequate to say the most! I'm not entirely sure how you would target a pseudoelement using jQuery - can javascript even detect changes in the DOM from CSS??

Comment: Found this... it may be of some help? It's adeveloper's take on targeting pseudoelements with jQuery... http://blog.asgaard.co.uk/2012/09/07/on-targeting-pseudo-elements-with-javascript-jquery (and associated fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/BtM7g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Daniela, I'd think the simple solution is to use positive and negative positioning. the LI is moved to the right (+20px) whereas the counter is moved to the left (-20px). I think it's easier to check this fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gbf6u/